# Google Drive Progress Upload/Download Status

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, download, google-drive-api

after search in the forum I need to ask a small example how to see upload/download progress status preferred in vb.net or C#.

### I have seen this post (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) with user 'DaImTo' answer but I haven't found nothing.

I have tried but I havent' XMLHttpRequest. I have only HttpWebRequest which doesn' t have neither 'open' event as suggested from your attached link.

But is not possible to use updload progress from request.upload?

Dim uploadProgress As Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress = request.Upload()

Do you have some link in .net?

Thanks

Comment: kudos for referencing one of the best wingers to grace the beautiful game

Answer (score 1):

The only way to implement an upload status is to use chunked uploads and update the status after each chunk.

For download status, you'll need to use XMLHttpRequest and use the techniques described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress