# How to make the download URL to return content-length in response?

Tags: google-drive-api

This page (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads) describes a method of obtaining download URL referred as Alternate method. This is what we use. We obtain this URL and then send GET request with this URL. The problem is that returned response does not have content-length and thus we cannot display a progress bar. Is there a way to force this URL to return content-length of the downloading content? We particularly interested in making this URL to return content-length because we pass the URL to different system which is specifically created for downloading and that system does not have logic calling GoogleDrive API. Here is example of the response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UobhZIKOBsST_-cDZt3BvIK2HSQ5ErTDPsA50BdhaAVrF9RD2Py-57pUoRnleNJnd_Xkg2_RoJClvYTzt0kZfaTSdQ61QB3tWXleX1RpefLObvFf2s
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Type, Date, GData-Version, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Origin, OriginToken, Pragma, Range, Slug, Transfer-Encoding, Want-Digest, X-ClientDetails, X-GData-Client, X-GData-Key, X-Goog-AuthUser, X-Goog-PageId, X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable, X-Goog-Correlation-Id, X-Goog-Request-Info, X-Goog-Experiments, x-goog-iam-authority-selector, x-goog-iam-authorization-token, X-Goog-Spatula, X-Goog-Upload-Command, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Disposition, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Length, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type, X-Goog-Upload-File-Name, X-Goog-Upload-Offset, X-Goog-Upload-Protocol, X-Goog-Visitor-Id, X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-JavaScript-User-Agent, X-Pan-Versionid, X-Origin, X-Referer, X-Upload-Content-Length, X-Upload-Content-Type, X-Use-HTTP-Status-Code-Override, X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier, X-Android-Package, X-YouTube-VVT, X-YouTube-Page-CL, X-YouTube-Page-Timestamp
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="bluemsx-code-1273.zip";filename*=UTF-8''bluemsx-code-1273.zip
Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2016 00:24:09 GMT
Expires: Tue, 04 Oct 2016 00:24:09 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Goog-Hash: crc32c=inH43w==
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) of download files in Google Drive API, there is no way to determine the content-length of a file.

So the alternative way, based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783623/google-drive-progress-upload-download-status), is you need to use [`XMLHttpRequest` in monitoring the progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) of your download.

`XMLHttpRequest` provides the ability to listen to various events that can occur while the request is being processed. This includes periodic progress notifications, error notifications, and so forth.

Another way that I found is this [tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/sdk-android-uploading-downloading-files) that uses a special handler for monitoring progress called `ProgressListener`. Just check the tutorial link for more information and sample code.

Comment: I'm not using JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest object. The code is in C# but like I said I cannot use C# Google Drive SDK in that place but it shouldn't matter. I perfectly aware of all possible progress monitoring techniques and even now I display how much data is downloaded but I don't know the total amount of data to download, so there is no progress bar but simple number of how many KBs is downloaded. Basically, the only question is how to get the total amount of data value if I have just that Google Drive download URL? By the way, the documentation does not say anything about content-length.